# Как ускорить executemany в Python при INSERT IGNORE (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, python, sql, база-данных, mysqlconnector

- Python 3
- mysql 5.7
- mysql.connector

Вставляю в базу большое количество значений (*~5 млн строк, пакетами по 5000 строк*) через executemany.

Некоторые значения не уникальны. В этом случае требуется просто пропустить эту вставку/обновить/заменить ее. Если использовать `INSERT` - при хоть одной ошибке в пакете на 5000 строк, при наличии дубликата не вставляется весь пакет. Скорость вставки высокая.

Для решения проблемы попробовал `INSERT IGNORE`, скорость падает в разы, впечатление что запросы выполняются по отдельности, а не пакетом.

Как можно решить данную проблему, без ущерба в скорости?

Comment: Попробуйте вставку с условием: IF (EXISTS(SELECT ...)) INSERT

Comment: когда вы говорите об уникальности - имеется в виду первичный ключ? Можете привести небольшой пример (анонимизированных) данных в вопросе?

Comment: Пример данных: id (AUTO_INCREMENT), email, password.  Может быть несколько одинаковых емайлов. Но у них должен быть разный пароль